# netty: How to edit the backend array of bytebuf in place?

Tags: netty, bytebuffer

In my use case, I need to xor each byte before reading from or writing
to the network. So I implement a duplex handler to do this.

But it's weird that I could not edit the output bytebuf in place,
while the reading side could:

```java
@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    ByteBuf res = buf.alloc().buffer(buf.readableBytes());
    buf.forEachByte(value -> {
        res.writeByte(value ^ cookie);
        return true;
    });
    buf.release();
    super.write(ctx, res, promise);
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    buf.forEachByte(new ByteProcessor() {
        private int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean process(byte value) throws Exception {
            buf.setByte(i++, value ^ cookie);
            return true;
        }
    });
    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
}
```

Note that the msg parameter of `write()` is ensured in `ByteBuf` type from
its previous handler.

If I edit the bytebuf in place in `write()`, the app could not work as
expected (I don't know what happens, my app is a proxy program, if I
edit buf in place, it would not work: some proxied connection would
give wrong content), so I have to fallback to copy the buffer to edit,
which is a slow manner, right?

Is there something special about the bytebuf in the `write()`?

**Edit:**

The proxy server handles two channels as a pair, the inbound channel and the outbound channel, and proxy data between them.

The pipeline of inbound channel:

```java
ch.pipeline().addLast("ReadTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(30));
ch.pipeline().addLast("WriteTimeoutHandler", new WriteTimeoutHandler(30));
cookie.ifPresent(c -> ch.pipeline().addLast(new FuzzHandler(c)));
ch.pipeline().addLast(new CopyHandler());
```

The pipeline of outbound channel:

```java
ch.pipeline().addLast(new CopyHandler());
```

The `CopyHandler` would `write()` the paired channel each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.

In some path of my codes, I `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer()` a static byte array and do `write()`, so if the `write()` in outbound handler modifies the buffer directly, it would change the byte array and affects the next reuse, so the content written to the network is wrong in half times.

So the solution is copy the byte array:

```java
ByteBuf buf = ctx.alloc().buffer(src.length);
buf.writeBytes(src);
```

BTW, what's the correct way to modify buffer in place? `setByte()` should use `readerIndex` as the offset?

```java
ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
final int readerIndex = buf.readerIndex();
buf.forEachByte(new ByteProcessor() {
    private int i = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean process(byte value) throws Exception {
        buf.setByte(readerIndex + i, value ^ cookie);
        i++;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it should be possible to adjust it in place. I suspect you may see issues as your write the same buffer multiple times (or different buffers which share the same storage).

Comment: I do not write the same buffer multiple times, at least not in my codes. The `ByteBuf` to modify is from the `channelRead()` of another channel.

Comment: I try to allocate new buf at the `CopyHandler` before `write()`, it doesn't work too. Only I could do is copy buf in `write()` of `FuzzHandler`. It makes me confused a lot. Why it makes difference? Does the original buf released somewhere before writing to the wire? (I edit my post, check it again please)

Comment: Please post a full reproducer here. Its hard to help without more details.

Comment: Could you check my mail? I sent you mail, but no reply then, so I have to post here to get attracted. You mail is norman_maurer@apple.com?